# Maven - Multi module project - How to configure/control plugin execution order

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

We have multi module project - currently when I trigger a build from parent pom file build starts and go through the various modules(generate jar files for each module) and bundle those to create single war file.

Here we have checkstyle configured, consider if we have any checkstyle violation Maven build will highlight it at the end of the build(almost after an hour) and results in unsuccessful build..

- How can we make the maven builds efficient which will check for checkstyle violation module wise and highlight for checkstyle violation before going for complete build..

OR

- Is there a way to trigger check style build for all modules before going for complete build in Maven..

Example: Consider I have 10 modules, if there is any checkstyle violation in module-3 build should stop and highlight about checkstyle violation instead of going through all the modules and highlight the same after 1-hour build..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have configured the checkstyle plugin from within the parent pom.

If this is the case, one solution would be to configure it in each individual child pom so that it runs as part of the child module build process.

This should result in the child build failing and killing the entire build early.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the build lifecycle in the child pom as given below.Like include

```
<failsOnError>true</failsOnError>

<project>
...
<build>
...
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```